# no exports were found that match the constraint contractname microsoft.visualstudio.portable library Android Portable Project

Tags: c#, android, xamarin, visual-studio-2015

I want to include a Class Library portable like image bellow:

[image]

However, I'm getting following error:

```
no exports were found that match the constraint contractname microsoft.visualstudio.portable library
```

[image]

I tried to delete a folder below but error keeps happening:

```
AppData\Local\Microsoft\VisualStudio\14.0\componentModelcache
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes the IDe downloaded zip files crashed, and the solution for me is delete the zip files and build again.

the zip files is in this path:

> C:\User\yourUserName\AppData\Local\Xamarin\zips

I hope that it was helpfull